# Redis cache not updating after model touch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

Here is my code in ProductCategory model:

```
  has_many :products

  def products_count
    Rails.cache.fetch([cache_key, __method__]) do
      products.count
    end
  end
```

In Product model:

```
belongs_to :product_category, touch: true
```

Once I create a new product I can see from the log the updated_at field being updated:

> ProductCategory Update (2.6ms)  UPDATE "product_categories" SET
> "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "product_categories"."id" = $2
> [["updated_at", "2021-08-04 15:34:55.520408"], ["id", 7]]    (1.7ms)
> COMMIT

Still:

```
ProductCategory.find(7).products_count // returns 0
ProductCategory.find(7).products.count // returns 1
```

If I execute Rails.cache.clear the results match so I guess Redis not regenerating cache after touch?

Comment: Using a counter cache would be perfect for your use case. Why your code doesn't work however is hard to tell without more info.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the value of *cache_key* I realised it didn't contain the timestamp value:

> product_categories/7

I added the following line to environment file:

```
config.active_record.cache_versioning = false
```

and the *cache_key* value is now correct and working properly

> product_categories/7-20210805073701479752